# nginx audio track for hls module installation

Tags: linux, nginx, nginx-config

I started to configure a setup with nginx audio track module and I encountered a few problems.

First of all, I started from the official [documentation](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/modules/audio_track/).

I followed the requirements and installed ffmpeg.

As far as I can see, the available libs are:

```
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libavformat.so.58
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libavutil.so.56
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libavcodec.so.58
```

When I run make install the following output is generated:

```
 /root/dev/nginx-audio-track-for-hls-module/ngx_http_aac_module.c: In function ‘ngx_http_aac_extract_audio’:
 /root/dev/nginx-audio-track-for-hls-module/ngx_http_aac_module.c:156:5: error: ‘av_register_all’ is deprecated [-Werror=deprecated-declarations]
      156 |     av_register_all();
          |     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
 In file included from /root/dev/nginx-audio-track-for-hls-module/ngx_http_aac_module.h:6,
 from /root/dev/nginx-audio-track-for-hls-module/ngx_http_aac_module.c:1:
 /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/libavformat/avformat.h:2050:6: note: declared here
     2050 | void av_register_all(void);
          |      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
 /root/dev/nginx-audio-track-for-hls-module/ngx_http_aac_module.c:210:5: error: ‘avcodec_copy_context’ is deprecated [-Werror=deprecated-declarations]
      210 |     avcodec_copy_context(output_audio_stream->codec, input_audio_stream->codec);
          |     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
 In file included from /root/dev/nginx-audio-track-for-hls-module/ngx_http_aac_module.h:5,
 from /root/dev/nginx-audio-track-for-hls-module/ngx_http_aac_module.c:1:
 /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/libavcodec/avcodec.h:4235:5: note: declared here
     4235 | int avcodec_copy_context(AVCodecContext *dest, const AVCodecContext *src);
```

This is only a short sample, there are many with the same error message.

Comment: The module wasn't updated in 6 years, so it is no wonder that it's giving errors with a recent ffmpeg.

Comment: Ok, so they should unpost the documentation from the official website?

Comment: Not necessarily. There are quite many modules listed there that will likely fail to compile with recent dependencies.